# What is vim's @@ variable?

Tags: vim

I know that by typing `@@` I execute the last @ command. But can anyone explain what `@@` is in the code below (found in the vim help files)?:

```
function! CountSpaces(type, ...)
  let sel_save = &selection
  let reg_save = @@

  if a:0
    silent exe "normal! `<" . a:type . "`>y"
  elseif a:type == 'line'
    silent exe "normal! '[V']y"
  elseif a:type == 'block'
    silent exe "normal! `[\<C-V>`]y"
  else
    silent exe "normal! `[v`]y"
  endif

  echomsg strlen(substitute(@@, '[^ ]', '', 'g'))

  let &selection = sel_save
  let @@ = reg_save
endfunction
```

It appears to be a register, but it isn't in the list at `:help registers`. From reading the code I'd guess it is the default register for yanking/deleting? Is this documented anywhere? All my searches just yield the `@@` idiom that executes the last @ command.

Comment: `@@` stores an AT-AT walker from Star Wars. :P

Comment: Interesting. It does seem to be the default register used by yank and friends, but I can't find any documentation about this. Stranger still, it does not appear to be connected to the `@@` command at all. Normally you can yank something into a register (eg: `"zy[motion]` yanks into z) and then "replay" it as keystrokes (`@z`) but `@@` does not replay the contents of the `@` register. It's a special case! I suppose it's good that replaying a register doesn't overwrite the default register used by yank and put, but it's kind of disconcerting that there's such an irregularity in vim's behavior.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`:help @r` gives me

```
register                        *expr-register* *@r*
--------
@r          contents of register 'r'

The result is the contents of the named register, as a single string.
Newlines are inserted where required.  To get the contents of the unnamed
register use @" or @@.  See |registers| for an explanation of the available
registers.
```

So, @@ will have the value of the text deleted with a `d`, `c`, `s` or `x` command,
or the the text yanked with a `y` command.

Comment: +1 so it looks like its "real" name is @", which kind of makes sense. You can actually yank something without specifying a register, and then "replay" it by typing the command `@"`. I wonder why the `@@` alias exists? And is there any way to programmatically determine what the `@@` command will do?

Comment: Ah ha! So, as L.G. said, it is really an alias for @". I guess that's why it doesn't show up in the list of registers.